# How to implements slider ads in android?

Tags: android, slider, swipe

Hi I am working with android applications.I am looking to make an SDK for ads.How can I make slider ads in which ads view  can swipe left to right as in startapp SDK??Please help me with your valuable suggestions :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use startapp for this...

visit [StartApp](http://www.startapp.com) for more information

Also Step 7 for detail information at this  [LINK.](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-&-InApp-Plus-Documentation)